# What can cause a parse error when installing a Cordova built apk?

Tags: android, cordova, parsing

I have used Cordova to convert my web-app into an apk.

The target devices for the app are OTPC (one tablet per child) tablets in Thailand.

These tablets have Google Play disabled, so apps must be installed manually. I have followed all the usual steps such as allowing unknown sources.

After building a -debug version of the app, it installed on my Galaxy Tab 3V without issue. It also installed easily on one of the OTPC devices commonly found in schools, but on the other I get the famed parse error.

Both devices are Android 4.0.3.

So I have spent some hours trying different changes to the Cordova config.xml file with no luck so far. My problem is that I'm hunting around in the dark with no indication of what is causing the parse error on this device.

So is there a way (e.g. installing via adb) of getting more info about this specific parse error.

For what it's worth, here is my most recent config.xml file. Perhaps someone can suggest changes:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.English_Builder" version="0.9.50"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"   xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<icon src="www/images/formatting/e_b_icon.png" />
<name>English_Builder</name>
<description>
    English Builder helps Thai students of English to build vocabulary and skills, through competitive timed activities.
</description>
<author email="iansamit@gmail.com" href="https://github.com/Iansamit/English_Builder">
    Ian Smith
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~2.3.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: by any chance did you copy and pasted this config.XML from somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the response Ghandi. Yes it's based on the default Cordova "MyApp".  After that I worked through their documentation on config.xml and changed what I thought was appropriate. The most recent change was from <allow-intent href="market:*" /> to <allow-intent href="*" /> since this is not being installed from Google Play.

Comment: The reason i raised the question is that sometime when you copy paste contents into config.xml some special characters and unicode characters will get copied to config.xml resulting in parse error. Better copy the contents once to notepad and then try copying it to config.xml Probably some extra spaces or special characters may cause this issue

Comment: @Gandhi Actually I started with the whole text file, then added to it. But I take your point; bits and pieces were added to it, copied and pasted from the Cordova website. Are you saying that when I do this, I should paste first into a blank text file, then recopy that into my config.xml?

Comment: Ya absolutely. or try to type it as much as possible. Infact when you create project using cordova create command, a vanilla config.xml file will be already available to you. All you need is to edit on top of it.

Comment: Did you cracked it?

Comment: Not yet, but you gave me an idea, thank you. I'm going to try making the vanilla Cordova MyApp into an apk, and see what happens. Then at least I'll know if I've done something wrong or there are restrictions on the device that perhaps cannot be worked through. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Was just curious

Comment: So the vanilla Cordova MyApp also resulted in the parse error. I suspect this is probably a political rather than technical problem, so will look into those solutions. Thanks for your help and interest @Gandhi

Comment: Political in the sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137573/discussion-between-thailandian-and-gandhi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally parse error is thrown when config.XML is not well formed or it has special characters in the XML.

In this case it seems to be an error related to android SDK version. The catch here is generally config.XML related issues will be thrown during the build time. But in this case the error is during installation which I overlooked.

So the conclusion is if you face parse error related to config.XML during build, it could be due to XML not well formed or special characters in it. If you face parse error during installation, one reason could be android SDK compatibility issue.

Update: Decompile your apk file and inspect android manifest file to check any android SDK compatibility issue

Comment: yes this is a more generic answer, so probably more useful to others that might end up here.

The only thing that might be good to add is: decompile your apk file, and examine the android manifest.  It was the manifest that gave me the clue as to what I'd missed in the config.xml.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Gandhi for steering me to the solution. The problem turned out to be that I'd neglected to put `android-minSdkVersion` or `android-targetSdkVersion` in my config.xml. So, in the manifest, the version code had defaulted to: platformBuildVersionCode="25", which is too high for 4.0.3

For reference, here is the relevant part of my revised config.xml:

```
    <platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
      <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
    </platform>
```

Comment: glad you cracked it. Posted my answer. Accept if it was helpful so that other users also get benefited. Cheers